# How to know what kind of device was plugged in?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using the next code to know when a device is plugged in:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
     //code...

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accesoryChanged:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accesoryChanged:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accesoryChanged:) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accesoryChanged:) name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];

     EAAccessoryManager *accessoryManager = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];
     [accessoryManager registerForLocalNotifications];
 }

- (void)accesoryChanged:(NSNotification*)note;
{
    if(note.name == EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification)
    {
        EAAccessory* accessory = [note.userInfo objectForKey:EAAccessoryKey];
        //code...
    }
    else if(note.name == EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification)
    {
        EAAccessory* accessory = [note.userInfo objectForKey:EAAccessoryKey];
        //code...
    }
}
```

And with:

```
accessory.name
```

I can get the device's name, but I couldn't find a way to know what kind of device is (i.e: a controller or a HDMI adapter).

Is there any way to get this information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `EAAccessory` object has properties for the `manufacturer`, `modelNumber`, and `serialNumber`. You can also look at the array of `protocolStrings` to get an idea of the device's capabilities.

> When deciding whether to connect to an accessory, you should use the accessory’s declared protocols to make your determination. The protocols associated with an accessory indicate the types of data the accessory is capable of processing. You may use other properties to help you decide whether or not to connect to an accessory but the list of protocols should be the key factor you consider.